# Longest 'increasing' path inside a square

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, inequality

Say you have a function $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that:

1. $f(0)=0$
2. $f(1)=1$
3. Let's just say that $f$ is everywhere differentiable (not really necessary)
4. $f$ is increasing i.e order preserving

Now what I'm trying to show is that the 'length' of such a function (i.e of it's graph) is always longer than $\sqrt{2}$ and always shorter than $2$.
The lower bound is pretty straightforward (shortest path is the diagonal of the unit square).
Now I'm struggling with the upper bound. I'm convinced it should be trivial, but cannot for the life of me find a proof.

Would greatly appreciate any help on the matter.
Cheers!

Comment: Doesn't it have to smoothly approximate $f(x) = 0\ {\rm for}\ (0 \leq x < 1 - \epsilon), 1\ {\rm for}\ (1-\epsilon < x \leq 1)$?  Use the Pythagorean Theorem or triangle inequality on portions of candidate solutions, perhaps.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork A sequence $f_n$ smoothly approximating your function would indeed satisfy $L(f_n)\to 2$. That is how I would show that 2 is the lowest upper bound. However, I fail to show that there are no functions of 'length' bigger than 2.

Comment: "longer than $\sqrt2$" is wrong, isn't it? These things matter!

Comment: @TonyK If it's differentiable it's definitely longer than $\sqrt{2}$. Using differential geometry, more specifically geodesics in the plane, you can show that the shortest path is the straight line. Pretty sure it should work without differentiability.

Comment: You missed the point: its length can be exactly $\sqrt 2$, which is not "longer than $\sqrt 2$".

Comment: A nice test function is $f(x)=x \exp(a (x-1))$. For $a=0$ it's just a straight line (path length = $\sqrt{2}$ and for $a \to \infty$ it approaches the boundaries of the rectangle.

Comment: A better criterion than "everywhere differentiable (not really necessary)" would probably be "continuous".

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The problem is symmetric with respect to exchanging x and y. It can got across and then up, or up and then across.

Comment: @Accumulation:  Yes it is.  But I need only find *one* of the limiting solutions to demonstrate the relation.

Answer (score 23):

Partition $[0,1]$ as $0 = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = 1$. Then, by the triangle inequality:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} & \sqrt{(x_{k + 1} - x_k)^2 + (f(x_{k + 1}) - f(x_k))^2} 
\\&\leq \sum_{k = 0}^{n -1} (x_{k + 1} - x_k) + (f(x_{k + 1}) - f(x_k))
\\&= (x_n - x_0) + (f(x_n) - f(x_0))
\\&= (1- 0) + (1 - 0)
\\&= 2
\end{align}
The length of a graph is defined to be the $\sup$ over all sums like the first line above. We have shown that all such sums are less than or equal to $2$, so the $\sup$ must be less than or equal to $2$. That is, the length of the graph of $f$ must be less than or equal to $2$.

Comment: I'll note that this doesn't prove strict inequality. I really have no idea how one would go about proving that, but it feels like it should be possible if we assume $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Thanks!
I was going back to the definition of length using the derivative of the curve and was struggling to majorize that ($L(f)=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+|f'(x)|^2}dx)$.

Comment: Is my proof clear? I found it a bit hard to write up because there are so many different notations used around this topic, and I didn't want to have to introduce my own before answering the question.

Comment: Yes, it's great thank you.

Comment: Now that I see it, I could've used the same square root inequality inside of the integral to get the $L(f)\leq 1+\int_0^1 f'(x)dx = 2$

Comment: Yes although it is perhaps worth noting that I only needed monotonicity of $f$. I didn't need differentiability or even continuity. I don't know how much you can weaken the assumptions to still get the $\sqrt{2}$ lower bound though.

Comment: That's correct, yours is probably best. One can still note that monotone functions are almost everywhere differentiable so we can still differentiate.

Comment: If the derivative exists and is $> c > 0$ on any interval then almost the same proof shows that the inequality is strict: you can take the supremum over partitions where some of the $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$ are contained in that interval and cover at least half of it (since these are cofinal under refinement and refining increases the sum) and on those $[x_i, x_{i + 1}]$ the triangle inequality is strict with some fixed error.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins It actually does prove strict inequality with one more observation: the $\le$ on the second line is strict unless one of $x_{k+1}-x_k$ or $f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)$ equals $0$. and that can't happen for every summand.

Comment: @GregMartin It can. Cantor's function is one such example. As the partition gets finer and finer, the summands will achieve equality in the above inequality for Cantor's function.

Comment: You're right, no individual finite partition can equal $2$, but the limit can equal $2$, my bad

Comment: Yes, I should have said "more and more of the summands will achieve equality." You're right that no indiividual partition can equal $2$, but the limit can. It really feels like it shouldn't be allowed. To me Cantor's function is even more pathological than, say, a Weierstrass function.

Answer (score 17):

If we assume $f$ continuously differentiable, using $$\sqrt{1+\lvert f'(x)\rvert^2} \le 1+\lvert f'(x) \rvert = 1 + f'(x)\label{first}\tag1$$ we get
$$L(f) = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+\lvert f'(x)\rvert^2} \,dx \le \int_0^1 \bigl(1+f'(x)\bigr) \,dx = 2 \text.\label{second}\tag2$$
Furthermore, since on some open interval $f'(x) > 0$ and then $\eqref{first}$ is strict, $\eqref{second}$ is strict.

Comment: Thanks !
I was missing the strict condition.

Comment: Just commenting to say that it turns out one really does need at least differentiability for the strict inequality. The Cantor function has all of the properties in the OP except differentiability (and indeed is differentiable everywhere except a set of measure $0$) and its graph has length $2$. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: I asked another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4738874/differentiable-and-non-decreasing-with-f-0-a-e-but-not-constant?noredirect=1&lq=1) which confirmed that $f$ being merely differentiable is enough to ensure strict inequality. We do not need to assume that $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Very nice! Another related question is then: if $\gamma$ is everywhere differentiable and $\gamma' \in L^1$ is $L(\gamma) = \int_0^1 \lvert d\gamma \rvert = \int_0^1 \lvert\gamma'\rvert \,dt$? If not (and in any case probably) you should add this as an edit to your own answer!

Answer (score 8):

Consider any monotonic candidate function $f(x)$ (even one that might, in principle, have a total path length $>2$), and two arbitrary distinct points along it (red).

[image: monotonic function]

We can always find another point (green) beneath $f(x)$ and replace the path between the red dots with a longer path (dashed) that respects the conditions of the problem.  By the triangle inequality, this new path is longer than the previous one.   (Of course, the $y$ coordinate of the green point must be non-negative, so as to conform to the conditions of the problem.)

We can perform this path-lengthening step infinitely many times and become arbitrarily close to the path length of $2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I like that approach, however I think it would require proving that this construction — when iterated — actually converges towards something of pathlength 2. And I think that is non-trivial (indeed the process is extremely local and pretty hard to formalize).

Comment: What is meant by "the green point must be non-negatoive"?

Comment: "the green point must be non-negative" means that its $y$ coordinate value cannot be less than zero (to conform to the conditions of the problem).

Comment: +1 The answers seems to explain the intuition.

Comment: How do you know that the dashed path is longer than the curve between the red points? This is just equivalent to the original problem (which is the special case where the red points are at (0,0) and (1,1).

Comment: @Especially Lime:  We can restrict my original construction to red points arbitrarily close together (yet a finite distance apart).  This is another (earlier) way of Charles Hudgin's solution.

Comment: This is a circular argument: the assertion "the new path is longer than the previous one" requires a scaled version of the statement we're trying to prove.

Comment: @GregMartin:  Not quite.  For a differentiable function, I can always take the steps arbitrarily close so that $f(x)$ can be approximated to any criterion by a linear function.  Then the triangle inequality comes to the rescue.

Comment: In other words, the given proof does not suffice. I agree.

Comment: @GregMartin:  Absolutely not.  Given that (in the limit) there are exactly *two* longest paths, finding one of them solves the problem as stated completely.  Over and done!  Or... we can say that the problem is mis-stated in assuming there is just one.  Either way, over and out!

Answer (score 2):

For every available direction $(dx,dy)$,

$$dx \ge 0, dy \ge 0 \implies \frac{dx+dy}{\sqrt{2}} \le \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} \le dx+dy $$

and the integral of $dx+dy$ over the whole path is $2$.