# Differentiable and Non-decreasing with $f' = 0$ a.e. But Not Constant

Tags: derivatives, examples-counterexamples, monotone-functions

### Context / Motivation

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737777/longest-increasing-path-inside-a-square/4737794?noredirect=1#comment10046832_4737794), the OP asks for a proof that if $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is increasing and differentiable with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, then the length of the graph $L(f)$ is less than $2$.

As is shown in the answers to that question, if we only know that $f$ is non-decreasing, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, we may conclude $L(f) \leq 2$. However, additional assumptions are required for the *strict* inequality.

If we additionally suppose, for example, that $f' > 0$ on some interval in $[0,1]$ (assuming nothing about the differentiability of $f$ outside of this interval), then we may easily obtain the strict inequality $L(f) < 2$.

By contrast, if we instead suppose that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere on $[0,1]$, we cannot guarantee strict inequality. The famous Cantor function has $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$, is non-decreasing, and is differentiable almost everywhere, yet $L(f) = 2$.

The above considerations made me curious how weak the hypotheses on $f$ could be. What seems to have gone wrong with the Cantor function is that the function was not differentiable everywhere, only almost everywhere.

This made me wonder whether it would be enough to assume that $f$ is differentiable everywhere. What could go wrong in this case? The only way to still have $L(f) = 2$ would be if $f' = 0$ a.e. But is this possible? Can we have a non-decreasing differentiable function with $f' = 0$ a.e., $f(0) = 0$, and $f(1) = 1$?

### My Question

Does there exist a function $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that

1. $f$ is non-decreasing
2. $f$ is differentiable everywhere (this rules out the Cantor function)
3. $f' = 0$ almost everywhere
4. $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$

Note that through re-scaling and translation this is the same as the question in the title. I have only asked it this way here to be consistent with with the context/motivation above.

Comment: Just because it confuses me for a second every time I see it, and it might get others too: Non-decreasing does not mean "not decreasing". It means "increasing (but not necessarily strictly)".

Comment: Correct. Do you think it would be more clear if I said "increasing but not strictly"?

Comment: Keep it as it is, "non-decreasing" is what it's called.

Comment: Isn't differentiable everywhere and zero derivative already too strong for it to be anything but a constant? The only reason the cantor function got away with it was you could allow jumps on the non differentiable points to make it act funny.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis yes, that was the point of my question. I was basically wondering if there was a function even more pathological than the Cantor function in this way. Turns out there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudin, *Real and Complex Analysis*, Theorem 7.21:

> If $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'\in L^1([a,b])$ then
> $$\forall x\in[a,b]\quad f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^xf'(t)dt.$$

(I.e.: [...] then $f$ is [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions).)

[Proof](http://sos440.blogspot.com/2017/02/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus.html)

Comment: Sorry to make you spell it out, but is our guarantee that $f' \in L^1([a,b])$ simply that $f' = 0$ a.e.?

Comment: Yes of course: if $g=h$ a.e. and $h$ is integrable, then so is $g.$

Comment: Seems so obvious, but for some reason (mathematical immaturity) I tend to only think of the FTC in the context of the Riemann integral. This is a good example of using the FTC in a situation where we need the machinery of the Lebesgue integral

Comment: I find this *Lebesgue* FTC not obvious at all.

Comment: You're right, the proof you linked certainly isn't obvious if you aren't very acquainted with analysis ideas. Also, am I missing something? Is the proof not just $f(x) - f(a) = \int_a^x f'(t) dt = 0$? Why do we need to talk about absolute continuity?

Comment: We don't need to talk about it. I just mentionned this equivalence for information.